# Is [0x02, 0x03, 0x00] valid data?

Tags: validation, protocols, message, checksum, stx

I am trying to write a program that returns valid data according to a message protocol within a `byte[]` array.

I have:

```
STX: 0x02
ETX: 0X03
DLE: 0x10 //Delimiter
```

Valid data is when the `byte[]` array contains STX, ETX, data and a correctly calculated LRC, for example:

```
byte[] validMsg1 = {0x02, // STX
        0x10,0x2,0xA,0x10,0x10,0x7,0x8, // Data 2 A 10 7 8
        0x03, // ETX
        0x2^0xA^0x10^0x7^0x8^0x03}; // LRC calculated from the data (with the DLE removed) plus the ETX
```

Invalid data example:

```
byte[] invalidMsg1 = {0x02, // STX
        0x10,0x2,0xA, // Data 2 A
        0x03, // ETX
        0x2^0xA^0x10^0x7^0x8^0x03,
        0x02, //STX
        0x05,0x44};
```

The byte might also contain random values around the valid data:

```
byte[] validMsgWithRandomData1 = {0x32,0x32,0x32, //Random data
        0x02, // STX
        0x31,0x32,0x10,0x02,0x33, // Data 31 32 02 33
        0x03, // ETX
        0x31^0x32^0x02^0x33^0x03,// LRC calculated from the data (with the DLE removed) plus the ETX
        0x2,0x3,0x00,0x02 //Random data
        };
```

My problems is that when I use the message with random data in and have `0x2,0x3,0x00,0x02` it breaks because it sees 0x02 and 0x03 as the STX and ETX and then it calculates LRC which results in 0x03 which results in this being returned: `0x2,0x3,0x00` with the last 0x03 seens as the LRC.

Question is this valid data:

```
byte[] data = {
    0x02, // STX
    0x03, // ETX
    0x00, // LRC
};
```

I am supposed to return the most recent valid data which is that but there is better data within this which is:

```
byte[] validData = {
    0x02, // STX
    0x31,0x32,0x10,0x02,0x33, // Data 31 32 02 33
    0x03, // ETX
    0x31^0x32^0x02^0x33^0x03,// LRC calculated from the data (with the DLE removed) plus the ETX
};
```

Comment: all data is valid if you don't tell us what protocol you're talking about

Comment: In general, in a message protocol. Are you allowed to have a message with just the STX,ETX and the LRC?

Comment: there is no "in general".  C0 control characters other than `BS` (and this one is a stretch), `HT`, `LF`, and `CR` are essentially obsolete (`NUL` is almost universally used to terminate a string due to the prevalence of C APIs, but this wasn't its original purpose).  Characters like `STX` and `ETX` have no meaning except when talking about a specific protocol like ANPA-1312.